# Postgresql md5 configuration: "No pg_hba.conf entry for ..."

Tags: postgresql

When trying to connect to Postgresql with user 'crm', I get the following error:

```
{myname}@{server} etc $ psql --host="10.0.0.129" --username=crm -W -d crm
Password for user crm:
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.0.0.129", user "crm",     database "crm", SSL off
```

Thing is, the pg_hba.conf file seems to allows exactly that combination of things:

```
#These are the only uncommented lines in the file
local    all             all                                     peer
host     crm             crm             10.0.0.129/32           md5
```

I've already restarted postgres with systemctl. Does anyone see the problem with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out if you've installed multiple versions of postgres, it creates a seperate data directory for each with a seperate pg_hba.conf file for each.